# Remove height of Div with Height: Auto? JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have finished building the .JS for my video player and somehow my positioning is making my div stretch (See here: http://prntscr.com/8tsl4m)

I want to remove that part but I am using six-columns class width from skeleton framework, so the div width dynamically changes. Therefore I cannot just define a height because it has to be auto.

Can I remove this with a line of JS or some CSS attribute that I am missing?

Keep in mind that I am just starting to figure out what JS is even used for, and and intermediate in CSS and HTML.

If you need my code then here it is:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 //INITIALIZE
 var video = $('#myVideo');
 
 //remove default control when JS loaded
 video[0].removeAttribute("controls");
 $('.control').show().css({'bottom':45});
 $('.loading').fadeIn(500);
 $('.caption').fadeIn(500);
 
 //before everything get started
 video.on('loadedmetadata', function() {
  $('.caption').animate({'top':-380},300);
   
  //set video properties
  $('.current').text(timeFormat(0));
  $('.duration').text(timeFormat(video[0].duration));
  updateVolume(0, 0.7);
   
  //start to get video buffering data 
  setTimeout(startBuffer, 150);
   
  //bind video events
  $('.videoContainer')
  .append('<div id="init"></div>')
  .hover(function() {
   $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':45}, 500);
   $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':-360}, 500);
  }, function() {
   if(!volumeDrag && !timeDrag){
    $('.control').stop().animate({'bottom':45}, 500);
    $('.caption').stop().animate({'top':-380}, 500);
   }
  })
  .on('click', function() {
   $('#init').remove();
   $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
   $(this).unbind('click');
   video[0].play();
  });
  $('#init').fadeIn(200);
 });
 
 //display video buffering bar
 var startBuffer = function() {
  var currentBuffer = video[0].buffered.end(0);
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var perc = 100 * currentBuffer / maxduration;
  $('.bufferBar').css('width',perc+'%');
   
  if(currentBuffer < maxduration) {
   setTimeout(startBuffer, 500);
  }
 }; 
 
 //display current video play time
 video.on('timeupdate', function() {
  var currentPos = video[0].currentTime;
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var perc = 100 * currentPos / maxduration;
  $('.timeBar').css('width',perc+'%'); 
  $('.current').text(timeFormat(currentPos)); 
 });
 
 //CONTROLS EVENTS
 //video screen and play button clicked
 video.on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
 $('.btnPlay').on('click', function() { playpause(); } );
 var playpause = function() {
  if(video[0].paused || video[0].ended) {
   $('.btnPlay').addClass('paused');
   video[0].play();
  }
  else {
   $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
   video[0].pause();
  }
 };
 
 //speed text clicked
 $('.btnx1').on('click', function() { fastfowrd(this, 1); });
 $('.btnx3').on('click', function() { fastfowrd(this, 3); });
 var fastfowrd = function(obj, spd) {
  $('.text').removeClass('selected');
  $(obj).addClass('selected');
  video[0].playbackRate = spd;
  video[0].play();
 };
 
 //stop button clicked
 $('.btnStop').on('click', function() {
  $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
  updatebar($('.progress').offset().left);
  video[0].pause();
 });
 
 //fullscreen button clicked
 $('.btnFS').on('click', function() {
  if($.isFunction(video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen)) {
   video[0].webkitEnterFullscreen();
  } 
  else if ($.isFunction(video[0].mozRequestFullScreen)) {
   video[0].mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else {
   alert('Your browsers doesn\'t support fullscreen');
  }
 });
 
 //light bulb button clicked
 $('.btnLight').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('lighton');
  
  //if lightoff, create an overlay
  if(!$(this).hasClass('lighton')) {
   $('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div>');
   $('.overlay').css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'width':100+'%',
    'height':$(document).height(),
    'background':'#000',
    'opacity':0.9,
    'top':0,
    'left':0,
    'z-index':999
   });
   $('.videoContainer').css({
    'z-index':1000
   });
  }
  //if lighton, remove overlay
  else {
   $('.overlay').remove();
  }
 });
 
 //sound button clicked
 $('.sound').click(function() {
  video[0].muted = !video[0].muted;
  $(this).toggleClass('muted');
  if(video[0].muted) {
   $('.volumeBar').css('width',0);
  }
  else{
   $('.volumeBar').css('width', video[0].volume*100+'%');
  }
 });
 
 //VIDEO EVENTS
 //video canplay event
 video.on('canplay', function() {
  $('.loading').fadeOut(100);
 });
 
 //video canplaythrough event
 //solve Chrome cache issue
 var completeloaded = false;
 video.on('canplaythrough', function() {
  completeloaded = true;
 });
 
 //video ended event
 video.on('ended', function() {
  $('.btnPlay').removeClass('paused');
  video[0].pause();
 });

 //video seeking event
 video.on('seeking', function() {
  //if video fully loaded, ignore loading screen
  if(!completeloaded) { 
   $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
  } 
 });
 
 //video seeked event
 video.on('seeked', function() { });
 
 //video waiting for more data event
 video.on('waiting', function() {
  $('.loading').fadeIn(200);
 });
 
 //VIDEO PROGRESS BAR
 //when video timebar clicked
 var timeDrag = false; /* check for drag event */
 $('.progress').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  timeDrag = true;
  updatebar(e.pageX);
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   timeDrag = false;
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(timeDrag) {
   updatebar(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 var updatebar = function(x) {
  var progress = $('.progress');
  
  //calculate drag position
  //and update video currenttime
  //as well as progress bar
  var maxduration = video[0].duration;
  var position = x - progress.offset().left;
  var percentage = 100 * position / progress.width();
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
  $('.timeBar').css('width',percentage+'%'); 
  video[0].currentTime = maxduration * percentage / 100;
 };

 //VOLUME BAR
 //volume bar event
 var volumeDrag = false;
 $('.volume').on('mousedown', function(e) {
  volumeDrag = true;
  video[0].muted = false;
  $('.sound').removeClass('muted');
  updateVolume(e.pageX);
 });
 $(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  if(volumeDrag) {
   volumeDrag = false;
   updateVolume(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
  if(volumeDrag) {
   updateVolume(e.pageX);
  }
 });
 var updateVolume = function(x, vol) {
  var volume = $('.volume');
  var percentage;
  //if only volume have specificed
  //then direct update volume
  if(vol) {
   percentage = vol * 100;
  }
  else {
   var position = x - volume.offset().left;
   percentage = 100 * position / volume.width();
  }
  
  if(percentage > 100) {
   percentage = 100;
  }
  if(percentage < 0) {
   percentage = 0;
  }
  
  //update volume bar and video volume
  $('.volumeBar').css('width',percentage+'%'); 
  video[0].volume = percentage / 100;
  
  //change sound icon based on volume
  if(video[0].volume == 0){
   $('.sound').removeClass('sound2').addClass('muted');
  }
  else if(video[0].volume > 0.5){
   $('.sound').removeClass('muted').addClass('sound2');
  }
  else{
   $('.sound').removeClass('muted').removeClass('sound2');
  }
  
 };

 //Time format converter - 00:00
 var timeFormat = function(seconds){
  var m = Math.floor(seconds/60)<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
  var s = Math.floor(seconds-(m*60))<10 ? "0"+Math.floor(seconds-(m*60)) : Math.floor(seconds-(m*60));
  return m+":"+s;
 };
});
```

```css
/* video container */
.videoContainer{
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
 background-color: #f2f5f8;
 color: #383737;
    border: 0px solid #f2f5f8;
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;}

/* video caption css */
.caption{
 display:none;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
 background-color: #f2f5f8;
 font-size:20px;
 font-weight:bold;
 background-color: #f2f5f8;
}

/*** VIDEO CONTROLS CSS ***/
/* control holder */
.control{
 background-color: #f2f5f8;
    font-family: Cabin;
 color: #383737;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 75px;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 z-index:5;
 display:none;
    height: 40px;
}
/* control top part */
.topControl{
 height:11px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #404040;
 padding:1px 5px;
}
/* control bottom part */
.btmControl{
 clear:both;
 height: 6px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #eef2f6;
}
.control div.btn {
 float:left;
 width:34px;
 height:30px;
 padding:0 5px;
 border-right:1px solid #404040;
 cursor:pointer;
}
.control div.text{
 font-size:12px;
 font-weight:bold;
 line-height:30px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:verdana;
 width:20px;
 border:none;
 color: #383737;
}
.control div.btnPlay{
 background:url(images/play.png) no-repeat 0 0;
 border-left:1px solid #404040;
}
.control div.paused{
 background:url(images/pause.png) no-repeat 0 0px;
}
.control div.btnStop{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat 0 -60px;
}
.control div.spdText{
 border:none;
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:30px;
 font-style:italic;
}
.control div.selected{
 font-size:15px;
 color: #383737;
}
.control div.sound{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -88px -30px;
 border:none;
 float:right;
}
.control div.sound2{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -88px -60px !important;
}
.control div.muted{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -88px 0 !important;
}
.control div.btnFS{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -44px 0;
 float:right;
}
.control div.btnLight{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -44px -60px;
 border-left:1px solid #404040;
 float:right;
}
.control div.lighton{
 background:url(control.png) no-repeat -44px -30px !important;
}

/* PROGRESS BAR CSS */
/* Progress bar */
.progress {
 width:85%;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
 cursor:pointer;
 height: 6px;
    background-color: #eef2f6;
}
.progress span {
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 display:block;
}
.timeBar{
 z-index:10;
 width:0;
 height: 6px;
    background-color: #db7560;
    
}
.bufferBar{
 z-index:5;
 width:0;
 height: 6px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #eef2f6;
}
/* time and duration */
.time{
 width:15%;
 float:right;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:11px;
 line-height:12px;
}

/* VOLUME BAR CSS */
/* volume bar */
.volume{
 position:relative;
 cursor:pointer;
 width:70px;
 height:10px;
 float:right;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
}
.volumeBar{
 display:block;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 background-color:#eee;
 z-index:10;
}

/* OTHERS CSS */
/* video screen cover */
.loading, #init{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
 z-index:2;
 display:none;
    z-index: 100;
}
#init{
 background:url(images/bigplay.png) no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
 cursor:pointer;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="six columns">
                <div class="videoContainer">
                   <video id="myVideo" controls preload="auto" poster="images/1-thm.png" width="600" height="350" >
                       <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                       <p>Your browser does not support the video tag.</p>
                   </video>
                <div class="caption">Screamer 2015 Intro</div>
                <div class="control">
                    <div class="topControl">
                        <div class="progress">
                            <span class="bufferBar"></span>
                            <span class="timeBar"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="time">
                            <span class="current"></span> / 
                            <span class="duration"></span> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btmControl">
                        <div class="btnPlay btn" title="Play/Pause video"></div>
                        <div class="btnStop btn" title="Stop video"></div>
                        <div class="spdText btn">Speed: </div>
                        <div class="btnx1 btn text selected" title="Normal speed">x1</div>
                        <div class="btnx3 btn text" title="Fast forward x3">x3</div>
                        <div class="btnFS btn" title="Switch to full screen"></div>
                        <div class="btnLight lighton btn" title="Turn on/off light"></div>
                        <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
                            <span class="volumeBar"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sound sound2 btn" title="Mute/Unmute sound"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="loading"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me... what exactly seems to be the problem?

Comment: There is a stretched out area on the bottom of the controls for the video

Comment: Have you tried setting video element width to 100%?

Comment: CSS::: video{  width:100%  }

Comment: It is not about the width. It is about the height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your div btmControl, there is the code

```
                    <div class="volume" title="Set volume">
                        <span class="volumeBar"></span>
                    </div>
```

for which I cannot see the use right now.
Try changing the corresponding height value in the css part (.volume and .volumeBar) or consider removing it (if it really is not useful)
Because it is set to

```
display:block;
```

it should create a new line and not fill in a row along with the other divs.
So `display:inline;` will also provide a possible solution

Furthermore, the following divs will also be aligned in a new line. I propose this is the line break you do not want to have...
(For an example of display:block effect [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=block))

But anyway, a fiddle version for this problem would be of great help!